# php array key doesn't exist but I can print_r it, so it does exist

Tags: php, arrays, exists, not-exists

I simplified this code to try to illustrate the issue.

This code says the 3rd key or index of the main array doesn't exist, when it actually does exist.

I have a MAIN array with sub arrays with Numbers.

another array with all the keys (1,2,3,4)

and then i do combinations of 3 keys (Ex. 1,2,3) picked from the keys array.

Then with the 3 keys, I get the Numbers from the MAIN array.

But since I get that the 3rd key doesn't exist, it's giving me problems with my main code.

At least, here you can see it says "it doesn't exist".

```
function combinations_FUNQ($n,$All_Keys_of_Main_Arr_ARR){
        if($n===0)
            return array(array());
        if(count($All_Keys_of_Main_Arr_ARR)===0)
            return array();
        $x=$All_Keys_of_Main_Arr_ARR[0];
        $TEMP=array_slice($All_Keys_of_Main_Arr_ARR,1,count($All_Keys_of_Main_Arr_ARR)-1);
        $res1=combinations_FUNQ($n-1,$TEMP);
            for($i=0;$i<count($res1);$i++){
                array_splice($res1[$i],0,0,$x);
            }
        $res2=combinations_FUNQ($n,$TEMP);
        return array_merge($res1,$res2);
    }

// ARRAY WITH MAIN NUMBERS
$Main_Arr_w_Nums = array( array(1,6), array(5,7,12,23,28,34), array(29,35), array(9,3), array(17,33,37) );

// ARRAY WITH ALL KEYS OF MAIN NUMBERS ARRAY
$All_Keys_of_Main_Arr_ARR=array(1,2,3,4);

// ARRAY WITH ALL POSSIBLE COMBINATIONS OF 3 OF THE PREVIOUS KEYS. EX. 1,2,3 ; 1,2,4
$allTenKeysCombinations_ARR=combinations_FUNQ(3,$All_Keys_of_Main_Arr_ARR);

// FOR EACH KEYS COMBINATION I WANT TO SEE THE MAIN NUMBERS
foreach ($allTenKeysCombinations_ARR as $key => $selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums){

    for($j=0;$j<=3;$j++){

        if(array_key_exists($j,$Main_Arr_w_Nums[($selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums[$j])])){
            echo 'GOOD: The key: '.$selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums[$j].' YES, exists<BR>';
        }else{
            echo 'PROBLEM: The key: '.$selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums[$j].' NO, DOESNOT exist<BR>';    
        }

            echo'Main_Arr_w_Nums:<pre>';
            print_r($Main_Arr_w_Nums[$selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums[$j]]);
            echo'</pre>';

        if(!isset( $selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums[$j])){
           $selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums[$j]=null;
        }

        if(!isset( $Main_Arr_w_Nums[$selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums[$j]])){
           $Main_Arr_w_Nums[$selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums[$j]]=null;
        }
    echo'<hr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: How about some extractions and the exact error code?  Is `echo 'PROBLEM: The key: '.$selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums[$j].' NO, DOESNOT exist<BR>'; ` where the problem is?  Had to dig through lines of mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here :

```
if(array_key_exists($j,$Main_Arr_w_Nums[($selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums[$j])])){
            echo 'GOOD: The key: '.$selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums[$j].' YES, exists<BR>';
        }else{
            echo 'PROBLEM: The key: '.$selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums[$j].' NO, DOESNOT exist<BR>';    
        }
```

when you are checking if array_key_exists, you should do it like this :

```
if(array_key_exists($selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums[$j],$Main_Arr_w_Nums))
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you are looking for $j, which isn't the array key you use later, inside the array value, not the full array.

Your key, from the next line down is stated as `$selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums[$j]` so that should be the key you look for inside the array `$Main_Arr_w_Nums`.

```
array_key_exists($selectedKeysFromMain_Arr_w_Nums[$j], $Main_Arr_w_Nums);
```

Comment: Thanks @Devon, that was it, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your for-loop runs 4 times and in the

```
$allTenKeysCombinations_ARR
```

you just have 3 elements in each array.

So use the for-loop as follows:

```
for($j=0;$j<3;$j++){ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks @Florian D, still it didn't work. It still says "PROBLEM: The key: 3 NO, DOESNOT exist", and right after that, I can print_r the array, so it exists.